# Crontab Error on Mac while using pyautogui module

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, cron

I'm running the below command(scenario 1)from Mac terminal and I get the desired output

***Scenario 1***

```
/Users/pd186040/OneDrive\ \-\ \Teradata/Documents/POC/Webex/webex.sh  >> /Users/pd186040/Downloads/script_output.log 2>&1
```

But while scheduling the command through crontab, Scenario 2 throws an error

***Scenario 2***

```
*/10 * * * *  export PATH=/Users/pd186040/opt/anaconda3/bin/:$PATH && python /Users/pd186040/OneDrive\ \-\ \Teradata/Documents/POC/Webex/webex1.sh  >> /Users/pd186040/Downloads/script_output.log 2>&1
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pd186040/OneDrive - Teradata/Documents/POC/Webex/webex1.py", line 21, in <module>
    button = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('/Users/pd186040/OneDrive - Teradata/Documents/POC/Webex/app.png', grayscale=False)
  File "/Users/pd186040/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 175, in wrapper
    return wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/pd186040/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 207, in locateCenterOnScreen
    return pyscreeze.locateCenterOnScreen(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/pd186040/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 400, in locateCenterOnScreen
    coords = locateOnScreen(image, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/pd186040/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 359, in locateOnScreen
    screenshotIm = screenshot(region=None) # the locateAll() function must handle cropping to return accurate coordinates, so don't pass a region here.
  File "/Users/pd186040/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 446, in _screenshot_osx
    subprocess.call(['screencapture', '-x', tmpFilename])
  File "/Users/pd186040/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 339, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/Users/pd186040/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Users/pd186040/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'screencapture': 'screencapture'
```

**Webex.sh is calling below python script**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Created on Thu Aug 27 18:39:22 2020

@author: pd186040
"""

import pyautogui
import time

while True:    
    button = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('/Users/pd186040/OneDrive - Teradata/Documents/POC/Webex/app.png', grayscale=False)
    if button != None:
        x = button[0] / 2
        y = button[1] / 2
        pyautogui.moveTo(x,y)
        pyautogui.click(clicks = 2)
        pyautogui.click()
        print("Clicked {0}".format('/Users/pd186040/OneDrive - Teradata/Documents/POC/Webex/app.png'))
        break
    else :
        print("Application is currently running")
        break
    
time.sleep(3)
 
button = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('/Users/pd186040/OneDrive - Teradata/Documents/POC/Webex/refresh.png', grayscale=False)
x = button[0] / 2
y = button[1] / 2
pyautogui.moveTo(x,y)
pyautogui.click(clicks = 2)
pyautogui.click()
print("Meetings Refreshed")
```

Comment: You tried using `locateOnScreen()`?

Comment: Yes, I did try locateOnScreen() , giving the same error